# Is horseback riding affecting my piano technique?

Tags: piano, technique, health

After horseback riding my fingers feel stiff, lazy and i feel like my technique has degraded. I think it's because the pulling on my hands. I know sport is a very common topic in piano forums, but I haven’t seen anyone talking about horseback riding. Can it do long-term damage to your hands? (Yes I use gloves, but they don’t seem to be very useful)

I might be a bit paranoid about this but I still want to hear you honest answers.

Comment: Have you just started horse riding?

Comment: Nope. I have been doing it for years

Answer (score 1):

If your piano technique returns to normal within an hour or two after riding, don't worry.  That sounds like the same degraded fine motor control that one gets temporarily after a gym workout.